# Read the digits for a number one at a time, checking for duplicates

Tags: c, syntax-error

The program is meant to receive a number, one digit at a time, and use that digit as an index for the array to check if it's true; if so then break out of the loop and if not, set it to true and continue scanning the other digits til it reaches the last. It's supposed to tell only if a digit was repeated or not at this point.

I have this code so far but I can't seem to get it working. Can anyone help me? I noticed while troubleshooting on my own by testing the value of the variables after execution that sometimes the digits aren't even read, only the first digit entered is read.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define true 1
#define false 0
typedef int bool;

int main(void)
{
  // Variables to contain the seen digits
  bool seendig[10] = { false };
  long entered;
  int container;

  printf("This Program Is Designed To Determine If Any Digits Has Been Repeated!\n Please Enter a Number: ");

  scanf("%1d", &entered);

  while (entered > 0) 
  {
    container = entered;

    if (seendig[container])
        break;

    seendig[container] = true;

    entered /= 10;

  }

  if (entered > 0)
    printf("\nThe Digit Was Repeated\n\n");

  else
    printf("The Digit Was Not Repeated\n\n");

  system("pause");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf_s("%1d", &entered)` is supposed to read the whole number or just one digit ?

Comment: `long entered;` --> `int entered;` and this has many problem.

Comment: Start by not `typedef`ing your own `bool`. Use the C standard boolean type and `#include <stdbool.h>`. Sidenote (not related): `bool seendig[10] = { false };` just happens to work, but does not have the semantics of setting all fields to whatever `false` is.

Comment: Your problem is that you read only one single digit here, put the `scanf_s()` in your while loop...

Answer (score 1):

The part

```
    container = entered;

                                            if (seendig[container])
```

will cause out-of-range access if 10 or larger integer is inputted.

I guess

```
container = entered;
```

should be

```
container = entered % 10;
```

to get the least significant digit in decimal.

Comment: @user3121023 I misunderstood it as `%ld`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but its only meant to receive one digit, so how would it matter whats in the container? if they entered more than one digits, it would use them one at a time, seeing that thats what the program was meant to do

Comment: Dear Theory of Infinity, you do honour to your name as `seendig[container]` will surely address infinity and will be out of bounds if a number larger than 10 is entered because your code does NOT process one digit at a time (and assuming %ld and not %1d, the latter making the program obsolete because in a one digit number no digit will ever be repeated).

Answer (score 1):

Is your code only trying to let the user input 1 number? or many number? If it is the latter then your `scanf("%1d",&entered);` should be inside of a loop and also I would recommend that you use a post-test loop or `do-while loop` since you need to let the user input a number first before checking it.

You should also consider **0** since it is a valid index value in an array

```
 do  {
    printf("This Program Is Designed To Determine If Any Digits Has Been Repeated!\nPlease Enter a Number: ");
    scanf("%d", &temp);


    entered = temp;
    if(temp >= 0){
        while(temp > 0){
            entered = temp % 10;
            temp/=10;
        }
    }else{      
        break;
    }

   if(entered >= 0 && seendig[entered] != true){
        seendig[entered] = true;
    }else{
        flag = 1;
    }
    printf("\n");
  }while(flag == 0);

  if (entered >= 0){
    if(flag == 1){
       printf("\nThe Digit Was Repeated\n\n");
    }else{
       printf("The Digit Was Not Repeated\n\n");
    }
  }else{
       printf("The Digit You have Inputted is a Negative Value\n\n");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add this line of code to end of your while loop

```
 scanf_s("%d", &entered);
```

Comment: Using `%ld` is the correct way to read `long` via `scanf()`. Are you sure using `%d` is correct for `scanf_s()`?

Comment: okay so firstly, im new to programming and im aiming to master c first, from what iv learned, altho %ld does handle long intergers, %1d is used to take 1 digit, which is what i want to do. If i change it to %ld , wont that just accept the entire thing and slap it in the variable? which isnt what i want. The book im using used a very similar code that i cant seem to get working either, i used scanf_s cause normal scanf wont build in visual b

Comment: yes the right way here is to use %1d. Just misspelled.

Comment: The correct format for the problem is `"%1ld"` (digit one, lower-case ell) to read a single digit into a `long`. Or change the type of `entered` from `long` to `int` since `int` is big enough to hold any single digit. It would better to put the `scanf()` — or `scanf_s()` if you're on Windows — in the loop condition: `while (scanf(…) == 1)`. Also, if the user types 314159, the first `scanf()` will read the 3, and the second will read the (first) 1 without waiting for new input, so the prompting is not appropriate. Maybe `fgets()` to read the line and `sscanf()` in a loop to read the digits.